# Not able to get the input from a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 radio butttons which is shown conditionally.I am initially showing the state as false and then toggling it in the onchange input.but I am not able to get the toggling done.what is wrong in this approach.the label and input radio is set in a row.

```
{ showGalleyF1&& <div  style={{display:'flex',float:'left',width:'100%'}} className='mySummary margTop36'>
   <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container margRight">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
                <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
              <label class="control control-radio margTop5 margRight" for="1">  <span>Business Class</span> </label>
              <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <input  id="1" type="radio"      
                 name="businessClass"
                 value= {airCraftLoadingSel.businessClass}
                 checked={airCraftLoadingSel.businessClass}
                 onChange={()=>onChangeClass()} />
                

                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container margRight">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
              <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
              <label class="control control-radio margTop5 margRight" for="2">  <span>Economy</span> </label>
              <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <input  id="2" type="radio"      
                 name="economy"
                 value= {airCraftLoadingSel.economy}
                 checked={airCraftLoadingSel.economy}
                 onChange={onChangeClass} />
                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flexCol justifyContentSpaceEvenly">
            <div class=" dialog__container_item input-container margRight">
              <div class="dialog__description_config">
              <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
              <label class="control control-radio margTop5 margRight" for="3">  <span>Premium Economy</span> </label>
              <div className={`dialog__description__radio`}>
                <input  id="3" type="radio"      
                 name="premEconomy"
                 value= {airCraftLoadingSel.premEconomy}
                 checked={airCraftLoadingSel.premEconomy}
                onChange={onChangeClass} />
                <div class="control-indicator"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>}
```

Comment: Set same name for the radio buttons to fix the toggle issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to make input name same for all radio buttons and only ID should be different to toggle checked.